# View Animation not animating

Tags: java, android, animation

Im trying to add a view which will expand from small to the entire screen in size while the user is holding down a button. The view is actually going to be a circle but just while testing Im keeping it as a square.

I have this code for the animation on `MotionEvent.TOUCH_DOWN`:

```
if (abortIndicatorView == null)
    abortIndicatorView = new View(this);

FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(50, 50);
params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
abortIndicatorView.setLayoutParams(params);
abortIndicatorView.setBackgroundColor(0x80FF0000);
((FrameLayout)findViewById(android.R.id.content)).addView(abortIndicatorView);

double height = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
double width = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
final float radius = (float)Math.sqrt(Math.pow(width, 2) + Math.pow(height, 2)) / 2;
Log.i(TAG, "Radius: " + radius);

abortIndicatorView.startAnimation(new Animation() {
    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        abortIndicatorView.getLayoutParams().width = (int) (radius * interpolatedTime);
        abortIndicatorView.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (radius * interpolatedTime);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean willChangeBounds() {
        return true;
    }
});
```

But it doesnt animate, the view gets added with 50, 50 in size and in the center, but nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `abortIndicatorView.requestLayout();` in `applyTransformation` and set a duration to the animation.

```
Animation animation = new Animation() {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            abortIndicatorView.getLayoutParams().width = (int) (radius * interpolatedTime);
            abortIndicatorView.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (radius * interpolatedTime);
            abortIndicatorView.requestLayout();// Add this line
        }

        @Override
        public boolean willChangeBounds() {
            return true;
        }
    };
animation.setDuration(1000);

abortIndicatorView.startAnimation(animation);
```